# Spring Data gemfire + No Available Server Exception

Tags: spring, gemfire

We are using **Spring boot** and **Spring Data gemfire** , We have configured a ClientCache *(PROXY one)* and trying to connect to our local region , When i do a region.put it gives the below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.geode.cache.client.NoAvailableServersException
    at org.apache.geode.cache.client.internal.pooling.ConnectionManagerImpl.borrowConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:234)
```

Running it as a pure java application , Im able to get/put from the cache.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: It smells like the Spring configuration for Geode hasn't booted the pool that points to the locators/ servers.  Either that, or you have a locator running but no servers. To determine which, I would need more context of the problem.